# Magento 2 Setup error on latest xampp version 3.2.2

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, magento2.2.4, setup, xampp

I've installed Xampp v.3.2.2 and downloaded Magento CE 2.2.4 & 2.3. but I am facing issue when installing them.

I get the following error::

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: "continue" targeting switch
>   is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 in
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, '"continue" targ...',
>   'D:\xampp2\htdoc...', 426, Array) #1
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444):
>   include() #2
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322):
>   Composer\Autoload\includeFile('D:\xampp2\htdoc...') #3 [internal
>   function]:
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Zend\Stdlib\Arr...') #4
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\Parameters.php(29):
>   spl_autoload_call('Zend\Stdlib\Arr...') #5
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(67):
>   Zend\Stdlib in
>   D:\xampp2\htdocs\MagentoCE224\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 941

I couldn't find any solution to fix this. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Xampp v3.2.2 uses php 7.3?

Probably should downgrade php to 7.2 as using continue throws the warning above in the latest php version

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/PHP-7.3/UPGRADING

Comment: Yes, I have downgrade my xammp version to 1 version back (current Installed version Xampp 7.2.13 / PHP 7.2.13) and issue got resolved. Thanks